# Change Launcher icon while installing the app in IOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, icons, launching-application

Is it possible to set the user selected icon as `launcher icon` while installing the application in **IOS**?

Our client was asking the requirement as while installing itself user can select their custom launcher icon for Iphone Application. please help me to find out the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without a jailbreak, no, you can not do it.

The icon and the background image used while loading the app are both static. The first thing you can change is after the app has loaded, then you could have a user chosen splash screen.

Comment: dont go with jailbreak.. we are using in standard way.

Comment: because we are not using jailbreak.